# Display the data on same page and not in popup in JSF?

Tags: jsf, popup, ajax4jsf

I have been given a task to display the data on same page which is currently displaying in popup. I have two buttons one is search and searchbooks. Search Books displays the result on the same page and on click of search a popup opens. I have to display the results as it is getting displayed on click of searchbooks.
Please find the below code for `search` button. The code for search button and searchbooks button are same but i dont understand why it is fetching different results. Where can the hidden code be written.. any idea?

```
    <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:214px">       
                    <a4j:outputPanel style="float:right;" layout="block">
                        <a4j:commandButton value="search" 
                            id="searchButton" execute="@form"
                            action="#{searchController.Search()}"
                            styleClass="myclass"
                            onclick="return myValue" render="checkPanel" />             
                        </a4j:outputPanel>
                </h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Please add your popup code as well

Comment: you mean the controller side?

Comment: No, stop. Please don't copypaste real code. Generally it contains way too much distracting noise and nonsense. Just create a MCVE and post it. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The button code that i have written. on click of that button a popup opens which i dotn want..i dont understand how the popup is getting opened. i am using mojorra

Comment: One more reason to create a MCVE. Starting to finally learn and understand what every single tag and attribute actually does by simply observing the behavior when you remove it and determining if it's relevant to the actual problem.

Comment: Follow @Balusc and on click on button action method doing all the magic so that result is displaying in popup window check if popup window have any condition to render the popup